# Type modeling with TypeScript and fp-ts and error while using Either

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

I'm trying to use TypeScript and `fp-ts` to get my feet wet in modeling 
domain logic with types and I've come across this problem:

```
import { left, right, Either } from "fp-ts/lib/Either";

type MyType = {
  id: string,
  isValid: boolean,
}

type MyValidType = {
  id: string,
  isValid: true,
}

type CreateMyValidType = (t: MyType) => Either<Error, MyValidType>

// Compile error!
const createMyValidType: CreateMyValidType = t => {
  switch (t.isValid) {
    case true:
      return right({
        id: "test",
        isValid: true
      })
    default:
      return left(new Error())
  }
}
```

The compiler yells at me because: 
`Type '(t: MyType) => Either<Error, { id: string; isValid: boolean; }>' is not assignable to type 'Either<Error, CreateMyValidType>'.`

If I remove the `Either` and I just return the sum type `Error | MyValidType` than it's fine.

```
type CreateMyValidType = (t: MyType) => Error | MyValidType

// This compiles
const createMyValidType: CreateMyValidType = t => {
  switch (t.isValid) {
    case true:
      return {
        id: "test",
        isValid: true
      }
    default:
      return new Error()
  }
}
```

It seems unable to recognize the correct type when it's inside `Either`!

I found I way to avoid the problem by specifying the types when `right` is called but I don't fully understand the implications so I don't know if this is a bad idea:

```
return right<Error, MyType2>({
  id: "test",
  isValid: true,
});
```

What is the proper way to deal with this issue and make it to compile?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

It works as expected with TS >= `3.4`

**Slightly longer answer**

As you might have already noticed, TypeScript is not really great at inference in general.
In your code sample, you provide an annotation for the return type of the function `Either<Error, MyValidType>`, so that TS can try to unify all the branches into the expected return type: without this explicit annotation, results would be even worse.

Even with the manual type annotation, pre-3.4 TS would be "lazy" and try to resolve all the generic type parameters declared by the `left` and `right` functions (both have `L` and `R` as type parameters) in place, without "waiting" to gain a better knowledge before taking that choice.
It would thus infer `Error` as `L` for the `default` case, and `{ id: string, isValid: boolean }` as `R` for the `true` case. The problem is that `MyValidType` requires `isValid` to be the literal `true` (more specific than `boolean`), and so it ends up failing with

```
Type '{ id: string; isValid: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'MyValidType'.
  Types of property 'isValid' are incompatible.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'true'.
```

With TS >= `3.4` the `R` is left "undecided" until later in the process, when TS actually knows the expected (annotated) return type of `createMyValidType`, and correctly sees the literal object as assignable to the declared return type.

You can read more regarding this improvement in the official changelog at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#higher-order-type-inference-from-generic-functions

*Note 1*

The issue is not really related to `fp-ts`, as with any generic function a similar problem occurs pre-3.4:

```
declare function identity<T>(t: T): T;

function f(): { foo: 'foo' } {
  return identity({ foo: 'foo' });
}
// Type '{ foo: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ foo: "foo"; }'.
//   Types of property 'foo' are incompatible.
//     Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"foo"'.
```

*Note 2*

Another way to look at this example is that TS does not infer the most precise possible literal types by default, except for some specific cases:

```
const foo = 'foo' // Type: "foo"

const fooObj = { foo: 'foo' } // Type: { foo: string }
```

This is a "safe" default considering JS mutability. This behavior can be changed using "`const` assertions":

```
const fooObj = { foo: 'foo' } as const // Type: { readonly foo: "foo" }
```

This is another addition in `3.4` (see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#const-assertions), which is not strictly needed in your example because of the return type annotation you have in `createMyValidType`.